# Informational text for rails runners

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optionparser

I have a script like

```
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opt.on("-h","--help","help") do
    puts opts
  end
end.parse!
```

But whenever I call `rails runner my_script.rb --help` it shows me help for the rails runner and not my script. Is there a way that I can prevent rails runner from swallowing up this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot do this with runner - runner first searches for its own options and in case of `--help` or `-h` it prints the help and exits before even checking whether your script exists or not:

```
# Railites: lib/rails/commands/runner
opts.on("-h", "--help",
    "Show this help message.") { $stdout.puts opts; exit }
```

You can however get around this by simply not using runner at all and writing pure ruby script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'optparse'

environment = 'development'

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opt.on("-e", "--environment") do |v|
    environment = v
  end
  opt.on("-h","--help","help") do
    puts opts
  end
end.parse!

# RAILS_ENV is used by environment.rb file to load correct configuration
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = environment
# Load your rails application
require_relative "../config/environment.rb"

puts User.count # Your code here
```